# How can I exploit a SQL Injection based on time without using single-quotes?

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, sql-server

I'm doing some test on a web application and I found a SQL Injection in a stored procedure. It's something like this:

```
Stored_procedure [input]
```

The stored procedure validates the input, it must be an integer, but I can inject another SQL sentence like this:

```
Stored_procedure 1;SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

The web application doesn't show me the result of the second SQL sentence, so I tried to execute a SQL injection based on time:

```
Stored_procedure 1;WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
```

It didn't work, because the web application scapes the sigle-quotes, then I changed my SQL Injection:

```
Stored_procedure 1;WAITFOR DELAY (CHAR(48)+CHAR(48)+CHAR(58)+CHAR(48)+CHAR(48)+CHAR(58)+CHAR(49)+CHAR(48));
```

This didn't work too, it generates an error. Could you help to know why it doesn't work or how can I exploit it?

Comment: Probably not without knowing what application and what error.

Comment: Did you try double qoutes?

Comment: You first need to find which SGBD is this service using.

Comment: The first stage of exploitation is enumeration. Please give us the info we need to figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to get past the scraping of your SQL statements, especially if it's not doing the scraping (or sanitization) of your input recursively. You can sometimes weasel the input in by means of encapsulating it with other characters you know will be filtered out, or sometimes by just putting a wack in front of each restricted or filtered character. For much more on the subject there are loads of great examples in The Web Application Hacker's Handbook, by Wiley Books, and I strongly recommend it. Seriously upped my SQLi and other web-app cracking game.